# How to decompile .exe to jar file?

Tags: jar, compilation, exe

the .exe application is written in Java

Comment: I voted to close this question. Although an accepted answer is available, it's completely out of context.

Comment: Maybe if the jar was first turned into an exe there is a way back to jar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if possible, you can do it by [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/)